# Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm trying create a jhipster project with Angular 6. When I run `ng serve` command, I got the following error.

```
Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
Error: Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
    at ServeCommand.getProjectNamesByTarget (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:184:19)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:58:43)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:122:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:112:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:109:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:141:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\pc\complexdemo\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: shall i add a code?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368343/angular-cli-6could-not-determine-single-project-for-serve-target

Comment: I have already looked at it.It didnt work for me.